# File downloaded with headers doesn't work

Tags: php, http, audio, http-headers, ogg

I'm trying to download an audio ogg file with a dynamic url

```
function getAudio($fileName){

    $localFile = __DIR__ . '/../../../shared/call_review/' . $fileName;
    $fp = fopen($localFile, 'r');
    $fp or die('Could not open file "' . $fileName . '"' . PHP_EOL);

    $contents = fread($fp, filesize($localFile));
    $contents or die('could not read file');

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Type: audio/ogg');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($contents));
    header("Content-Type: audio/ogg");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);

   echo $contents;
   exit();
}
```

But after file is saved, it doesn't work, or is corrupt.

Comment: first of all, check if no errors are presented in downloaded file (text error message instead of file). Second you should check if there aren't any empty line or so before file content

Comment: As Michal wrote, open the "corrupt" file in notepad. There is likely a warning above the actual content. Also, [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) may be a better function than `echo/fread/fopen`.

Comment: The original file works.
It does not work just after is has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($contents));
```

The file size should come from `filesize($localFile)` as demonstrated several lines earlier,
so it should be:

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($localFile));
```

Or just use the length of the `$contents` variable:

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($contents));
```